# Error in cor(data[, -1], use = "complete.obs") : 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, csv, regression

I'm completely new to R - really have no clue what I'm doing to be honest. But I really need to run bivariate/multivariate regressions with this data following someone's advice and I'm stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
rm(list=ls())  
setwd("C:/Users/Bogi/Documents/School/Honors Thesis/Voting and Economic Data")  
data<-read.csv("BOGDAN_DATA1.csv")  
head(data)

round(cor(data[,-1],use="complete.obs"),1)  
Error in cor(data[, -1], use = "complete.obs") : 'x' must be numeric
```

dput

```
structure(list(REGION = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Altai Republic", 
"Altai Territory", "Amur Region", "Arkhangelsk Region", "Astrakhan region", 
"Belgorod region"), class = "factor"), PCT_CHANGE_VOTE = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 1L), .Label = c("-13%", "-16%", "-17%", "-25%", 
"-26%", "2%"), class = "factor"), PCT_CHANGE_GRP = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("10%", "17%", "19%", "27%"), class =    "factor"), 
PCT_CHANGE_INFLATION = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L
), .Label = c("-2%", "-3%", "-4%"), class = "factor"), PCT_CHANGE_UNEMP =   structure(c(5L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 3L), .Label = c("-13%", "-14%", "-17%", "-3%", 
"5%", "7%"), class = "factor"), POVERTY = c(18.6, 22.6, 20.4, 
14.4, 14.2, 8.6), POP_AGE1 = c(25.8, 16.9, 18.5, 17.1, 17.8, 
15.2), POP_AGE2 = c(58.8, 59.6, 61.3, 60.4, 60.8, 60.3), 
POP_AGE3 = c(15.4, 23.5, 20.2, 22.5, 21.4, 24.5), POP_URBAN = c(28.7, 
55.2, 67, 76.2, 66.7, 66.4), POP_RURAL = c(71.3, 44.8, 33, 
23.8, 33.3, 33.6), COMPUTER = c(46.4, 54.5, 66.1, 74, 65.1, 
55.2), INTERNET = c(32.1, 41, 50.7, 66.5, 60, 50.7)), .Names = c("REGION", 
"PCT_CHANGE_VOTE", "PCT_CHANGE_GRP", "PCT_CHANGE_INFLATION", 
"PCT_CHANGE_UNEMP", "POVERTY", "POP_AGE1", "POP_AGE2", "POP_AGE3", 
"POP_URBAN", "POP_RURAL", "COMPUTER", "INTERNET"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Check the `str(data)` for finding the class of the columns.  If the `data[-1]` columns are non-numeric, there is a possibility that you can get this error.  Please use `dput` to show the output of first few lines `dput(droplevels(head(data)))`

Comment: Columns 2 to 5 are factors.

Comment: Sorry but what does that mean? What do I need to fix?

Comment: As mentioned by @Pascal, you have `%`  in columns 2:5, which makes it `non-numeric`.  YOu could  remove those `%` and convert to `numeric` by `as.numeric(as.character(data[,2]))` if those needs to be in the `cor` calculation

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it so much! As a side note... do you have any suggestions where I would be able to teach myself R, at least basic knowledge?

Comment: @BogdanWarbucksBelei  You could start reading the intro materials http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf and check the coursera.org for any free R courses, and there are plenty of online resources ...

Comment: @BogdanWarbucksBelei I recommend you take a look to the [Quick-R tutorial](http://statmethods.net)

Answer (score 1):

You could loop the columns 2:5 (`lapply(data[2:5], ..)`), remove the `%` in columns 2:5 (`gsub('[%]',..)`) and convert the columns to `numeric`. The output from `gsub` will be `character` class, convert it to `numeric` by `as.numeric`

```
data[2:5] <- lapply(data[2:5], function(x) 
                  as.numeric(gsub('[%]', '', x)))

Cor1 <- round(cor(data[-1],use="complete.obs"),1)
```

Or you could remove the `%` in those columns using `awk` on shell (assuming `,`
 as delimiter)

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS=","} function SUB(F) {sub(/\%/,"", $F)}{SUB(2);SUB(3);SUB(4);SUB(5)}1' Bogdan.csv > Bogdan2.csv
```

Read the file with `read.csv` and run the `cor`

```
 dat1 <- read.csv('Bogdan2.csv')
 Cor2 <- round(cor(dat1[-1], use='complete.obs'), 1)
 identical(Cor1, Cor2)
 #[1] TRUE
```